# Async Composition behaviour

Tags: c#

Would like to understand the idea for async/await awaiting multiple tasks. Below find code from @Stephen Clary's webpage. I just added method DoIndependentJob1() and DoIndependentJob2() for testing purposes.

**First method (DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync)**
Seems to be clear to me (please of confirmation that i understand it correctly:

- We run 3 tasks and they starting doing the jobs
- Meantime DoIndependentJob run as well.
- Then before DoIndependentJob2 could be run all three tasks has to be finished

**Second method (GetFirstToRespondAsync):**
 - We run 2 tasks and they starting doing the jobs
 - Meantime DoIndependentJob run as well.
 - Now we await any of 2 tasks (one of them will be 1st)
 - Let's say WebService1Async was the one

and what's then?? Does DoIndependentJob2() will be fired even if WebService2Async still running and means WebService2Async will be just fired and forget in this case as we do not await it? Don't get that point please of clarification...

```
public async Task DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync()
{
  Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
  tasks[0] = DoOperation0Async();
  tasks[1] = DoOperation1Async();
  tasks[2] = DoOperation2Async();
  // At this point, all three tasks are running at the same time.

  //Doing some independent jobs
  DoIndependentJob()

  // Now, we await them all.
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

//Doing some independent jobs
  DoIndependentJob2()
}

public async Task<int> GetFirstToRespondAsync()
{
  // Call two web services; take the first response.
  Task<int>[] tasks = new[] { WebService1Async(), WebService2Async() };

 //Doing some independent jobs
  DoIndependentJob()

  // Await for the first one to respond.
  Task<int> firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

//Doing some independent jobs
  DoIndependentJob2()

  // Return the result.
  return await firstTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

Your `GetFirstToRespondAsync` method will await for either of the tasks to complete, at which point it will continue, with `firstTask` referring to that task.

When the other task completes doesn't matter. As you say, "fire and forget", well, rather "fire, and then optionally forget".

So the other task might still be running when you return from your method, or it may have completed, perhaps it even completed after the first task completed but before `DoIndependentJob2` was called, who knows.

Comment: hmm. Means that i will get the result of 1st task who was the first. Why also in return statment there is await?? Await is already two lines above (forgot to ask about that). Second thing strange is that when i do try/catch in the underlying methind which uses GetFirstToRespondAsync as await GetFirstToRespondAsync what if secnd tasks raise an error - as it is fire and run the error will not be catched means i cannot handle 2nd task... Is it right? If so what is the sense of it?

Comment: You're first awaiting to get the first task that completed. The result of that await is a `Task<int>`. This task has completed, which is why you got it. To get the result you can either read the .Result property of it, or await it. Awaiting a completed task will simply return the result directly. So that's just a way to grab the int out of the task to return it.

Comment: yes i understand but still not answer to my question. What is the sense for rest task after get response from first task, since they are unable to catch error as they fire and forget? WHat if there will be error. The underlying method's await DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync within try/catch will not catch error from the other tasks... If i am not mistaken.

Comment: I don't get your question. If you care about the other task, don't ignore it.

Comment: I just ment why to await only for one task out of two and then return result of that task when second task could be still working and we will not get that result and we even not able to catch error from that second task. P.S Why in return statment we have also await?

Comment: I can't answer that. Whoever wrote that code would presumably know why he opted to only wait for one task and ignore the other, there is no way I can second-guess that decision or try to explain it. Why there is an await on the return is commented a few comments up.